# Replacing tags in braces, even nested tags, with regex

Tags: php, regex

**Example**

```
preg_replace('/\{[a-zA-Z.,\(\)0-9]+\}/', 'Replaced', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit {tag1({tag2()})}, consectetur adipiscing elit.');
```

The result:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit {tag1(Replaced)}, consectetur adipiscing elit.

**Question**

As you can see "tag2" has been replaced, But I want to replace "tag1"
Do anyone know how I can do this?

(In some cases it might be like this:`{tag1({tag2({tag3()})})})` and so on.)

Btw I am actually using preg_replace_callback, but its easier to show it with `preg_replace`

Here is a site where you can test the code: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: What's the difference between `something.something` and `print.print` in your example?

Comment: By "replace everything but: `something.something`" do you mean that given the sample text, the returned string from `preg_replace` should be `something.something`... or do you want to replace *everything in curly braces* with *the first `something.something` style value*?

Comment: The result should be something.something Everything else must be replaced .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add curly braces to your character set.  Here's the pattern I used:

```
/\{[a-zA-Z.,\(\)\{\}0-9]+\}/
```

And here was the result:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit Replaced, consectetur adipiscing elit."
```

Comment: Tanks!, it works :) Iam almost there now i think.

Do you know a pattern to replace everything except something.something in the result i got: {something.something({print.print(param1,param2)},param2)}
something.something can be: [a-zA-Z.]

Answer (score 1):

Once you start talking about matching nested patterns (eg: matching the inner bracketed group in something like `(foo (bar) fu)`), then regex is the wrong tool. Regular Expressions are stateless, which, in this case, means that they can't count how many brackets are open.

If you are looking to do something like that, you might need to look into a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser)

Comment: Although it's correct for pure regular expressions, the PCRE used in PHP supports recursive matching (`(?R)`).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx):

```
<?php
$subject = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit {tag1({tag2()})}, consectetur adipiscing elit.';

pattern('\{[a-zA-Z.,()0-9]+\}')->replace($subject)->first()->with('Replaced');
```