# Php preg_replace pattern help

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP preg_replace need help with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723916/php-preg-replace-need-help-with-pattern)

I have this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   {something.something({print.print(param1,param2)},param2)},
>   consectetur adipiscing elit.

Where i  need a pattern that can replace everything but: `something.something`

The text something.something can contain `[a-zA-Z.]`

(I am using preg_replace)

Here is a site where you can test the code: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php